# ExceptionInInitializerError and NullPointerException in java

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to write a program that reads data from a pdf file into a string. Ultimately I want to interpret that string. I tried the following code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        
        File file = new File("/Users/s/Documents/test_1-001.pdf");
        PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(file);
        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);
        System.out.println(text);
        document.close();
}
```

I always get this error though:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha2/org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.createView(COSStream.java:222)
    at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha2/org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.getContentsForRandomAccess(PDPage.java:189)
    at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha2/org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFStreamParser.<init>(PDFStreamParser.java:59)
    at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha2/org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:505)
    at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha2/org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:489)
    at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha2/org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:158)
    at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha2/org.apache.pdfbox.text.LegacyPDFStreamEngine.processPage(LegacyPDFStreamEngine.java:153)
    at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha2/org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:361)
    at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha2/org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPages(PDFTextStripper.java:287)
    at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha2/org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:234)
    at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha2/org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.getText(PDFTextStripper.java:201)
    at AuslesenDerPDFDetails/auslesenDerPDFDetails.AuslesenDerDetails.main(AuslesenDerDetails.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.commons.logging.Log.error(Object, java.lang.Throwable)" because "org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils.LOG" is null
    at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha2/org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils.unmapper(IOUtils.java:273)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at pdfbox.app@3.0.0-alpha2/org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils.<clinit>(IOUtils.java:62)
    ... 12 more
```

Apparently my line

```
String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);
```

contains some sort of error. No object is null at this point though and I am defining every variable before I use it.

Can someone help?

Comment: looks as if you have a problem with the logging - maybe some conflicting or non-existent configuration of pdfbox logging?

Comment: I am still facing this issue, can somebody help?